# About using the Microsoft Chart library and a general clarification sought in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-charts

I am using the Microsoft Chart.

I have a UI to get the value for each property of this object. Then i store all these values in the DB.

Now that I have the properties from the DB I have to bind them to the corresponding properties of the Chart object.

Which is the most efficient and right way. Shall i do it using reflection or other ways.

I came to know that this class has a method that can export all the settings for the chart, including the values in an XML format. What if i can try to create an import data and properties method.

suggest the best way. I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with C# and VS2010.

> edit

I tried to get the xml from the Chart Object calling SaveAsXml() and then used that to load it as a template and tried back to get the chart object. that does not event work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to Use jQuery Charts for better UI control and to use MS Charts for hiding data from the user.